# cannot run Node.js IBMMQ v9.17

Tags: node.js, docker, ibm-mq

I'm trying to run Node.js app (12.x or 14.x) that uses IBMMQ 0.9.17 library in Docker container and getting this error:

```
Error: Dynamic Linking Error: Error loading shared library /opt/mqm/lib/libmqm_r.so: Exec format error
```

C client has been installed and env variables set properly:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /opt/mqm/lib64:/opt/mqm/java/lib64:
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = /opt/mqm/lib64:/opt/mqm/java/lib64:
```

Docker Image:

```
Darwin Kernel Version 20.5.0
```

what does "Exec format error" mean?

Comment: That generally means the library was compiled for the wrong architecture. You might need to be more specific about what you're actually doing and/or how you're doing it, specifically your docker image at least.

Comment: Your error message refers to /opt/mqm/lib/ and yet your library path is set to /opt/mqm/lib64/. Are you 32 or 64 bit? Also, your error message is looking for libmqm but you mention the client has been installed.  Are you trying to use client or local bindings?

Comment: The Node code tries several places to load libmqm. The most likely reason for failure is that the *_LIBRARY_PATH variable is not pointing to the right places or that the package has not been correctly unpacked.

That printed error is the final one in the chain, when it hasn't been able to load from anywhere else. Trying /opt/mqm/lib was the last fallback, after lib64. It always uses libmqm, even for client mode - all the usual mechanisms can force client mode. (In many situations, the MQ code is run from the Redist package under a local directory so client mode is the only option).

Comment: I see "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" - Are you running the Docker container on macOS (Mac OS X)?  If so, what release of IBM MQ are you trying to use?

Comment: trying to run in Docker with ibmmq 0.9.17

Comment: @JohnGlabb You mean IBM MQ v9.1.0.7 but for what platform/OS?  And what OS are you running your Docker container on?